# Can I use a htmlfile with text for my existing pdf

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, pdf, itext

I have a question to add text in a existing pdf with itextsharp. I want to add the text out of a html.

here my code:

```
string oldfile = Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/zugang.pdf");
string newfile = @"C:\test.pdf";

PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(oldfile);
Rectangle size = reader.GetPageSizeWithRotation(1);

Document doc = new Document(size);

FileStream fs = new FileStream(newfile, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, fs);

doc.Open();

PdfContentByte cb = writer.DirectContent;

BaseFont bf = BaseFont.CreateFont(BaseFont.HELVETICA, BaseFont.CP1252, BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED);
cb.SetColorFill(BaseColor.BLACK);
cb.SetFontAndSize(bf, 16);



cb.BeginText();

string text = "tedsfdsfdshfdsdfsdsdsdsvdsgdsdsgsg";


cb.ShowTextAligned(1, text, 600, 300, 0);
cb.EndText();

PdfImportedPage page = writer.GetImportedPage(reader, 1);
cb.AddTemplate(page, 0, 0);

doc.Close();
fs.Close();
writer.Close();
reader.Close();
```

But I want that I can use a html file for this. Can I use a html file for this??

here my htmlfile:

```
<p>Sie haben einen Gastzugang für [Anrede] [Vorname] [Nachname],[Firma] eingerichtet.</p>
                                                       Im folgenden finden Sie die Zugangsdaten
                                                       die für die Anmeldung am Netzwerk benötigt werden.Weitere Informationen stehen auf der Anmeldeseite zur Verfügung.
                                                        <p>

                                                            <b>Benutzername:</b>
                                                            <b>[Benutzername]</b>
                                                            </br>
                                                            <b>Passwort:</b>
                                                            <b>[Passwort]</b>

                                                        </p>
                                                       Der Zugang wird vom [ZeitVon] bis [ZeitBis] freigeschaltet sein.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, iTextSharp supports HTML to PDF . 
Here is [how](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/203481/HTML-convert-to-PDF-using-itextsharp)